Visual Studio Remote development "attach visual studio code" always connecting to dev container as root?
I have a docker container running and I attempt to use the docker extension to "attach visual studio code" to the container. This always connects me as root, though I want to connect as a user.
The user is created in the container upon creation using scuba and is not created in the DockerFile.
Whenever VSCode does connect to the container, it is always as root and causes many issues like not being able to see any directories for one.
I have tried setting the remoteUser and containerUser variables in the .devcontainer.json of the container, both of these do not work...
I have also changed the docker.commands.attach command execution in settings.json to include a user argument: --user=$USER.  This works for attaching via shell but not via VSCode.
Any ideas?
